# redux-persist rendering SSR application twice with React v18

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-persist

I am currently working on updating a Next.js application with SSR from v12 to v13. The update requires a minimum React version of 18.

Upon running the application I noticed that the application was being rendered twice. Further investigation led me to find that this is due to `redux-persist`.

Since the current implementation uses server side rendering, we need to ensure the page is rendered on server side. `redux-persist` runs on the client side, so we have this logic:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

function PersistStore(props) {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // Not on browser, nothing to persist here
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {props.children}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  // client
  return (
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={props.persistor}>
      {props.children}
    </PersistGate>
  );
}

export default PersistStore;
```

`PersistStore` is then called in `_app`:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
      {({ store }) => (
        <PersistStore persistor={store.__persistor}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PersistStore>
      )}
    </ReactReduxContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

This ensures that the page renders on server side and adds PersistGate on client side.

Using Next.js v12 with React v17.0.2 works as expected, however Next.js v13 (React v18) renders both versions rather than replacing the server side render with the client side render.

I have been following the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240) and tried two suggested solutions ([pass a function to `PersistGate`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240#issuecomment-647699316) and [remove `PersistGate`, use persistStore(store)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240#issuecomment-854471689)). To a certain extent they solve the problem, however redux persist's rehydration does not run immediately which can lead to further issues.

My suspicion is that this is an issue of `redux-persist` with React v18, it has nothing to do with Next.js. I have replicated the issue on Stackblitz with a simple Counter application:

- [Next v12 + React v17.0.2 + Redux](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-knv7fu) ✅
- [Next v12 + React v18 + Redux](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jsjjv3) ❌
- [Next v13 + React v18 + Redux](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zbjewc) ❌

I might try testing a plain React app to see if it makes a difference.

It's quite a specific issue but I'm hoping someone faced a similar problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Update

Issue has been replicated using plain React with SSR:

- [React v17.0.2 + Redux](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssr-example-z5yb6h) ✅
- [React v18 + Redux](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssr-example-3zraba) ❌

This might be a configuration issue really but it does show that the issue is with `PersistGate` on React v18.

---

## Update 2

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1452) on `redux-persist` GitHub repo.

Not seeing a lot of activity in recent months :/ Still hoping someone can help out on this one.